# Get price from mysql between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

In mysql database I have table like this:

```
StartDate       EndDate         Price
01.01.2017      01.06.2017      100
02.06.2017      01.12.2017      150
```

What is the best solution to get price between some days. For example if I send dates `25.05.2017 as start date` and `05.06.2017 as end date` I need to get sum of price between these dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select sum(Price) as total_price from table_name 
where StartDate >= 'given_startdate' and EndDate <= 'given_enddate'
```

Comment: I need sum of price for each day between two given dates.

Answer (score 0):

To find overlapping periods use following logic:

```
where start_1 <= end_2 and end_1 >= start_2
```

in your case:

```
where startdate <= date '2017-06-05' and enddate >= date '2017-05-25'
```

Edit:

Seems like you want to expand the date range to one row per day. Join to a calendar table (if you don't have one, yer, create it, you will used it in many places):

```
select sum(price)
from mytable join calendar
  on calendardate between startdate and enddate
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If I use this I got only one price. But I need sum of price for each day between two dates.

Comment: @Hajrudin: This WHERE will return both rows of your example data.

Comment: Yes it will. It will return me price for both periods. But I need sum of price for each day between these two dates. From this query I got result 250 as total price but I need to get 1400 as total price.

Comment: @Hajrudin: Join to a calendar table using `calendardate between startdate and enddate`

Comment: Sorry but can you explain me little bit better?

here is my current query. 

select sum(price) from price_periods 
where startDate <= '2017-06-05' and endDate >='2017-05-25' group by price

Comment: what should I have in calendar table ?

Comment: @Hajrudin: All dates for a range of years and everything you ever need to calculate based on those dates, e.g. week numbers, holidays, working day y/n. Search for *calendar table script mysql*, e.g https://gist.github.com/bryhal/4129042